# How to set working directory in CMake Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem with setting the working directory with CMake (Visual Studio 2022).

I'm currently working on a project (some OpenGL learning stuff) and decided to switch from typical VS solution-project to CMake project. I need to load some files (.obj, shaders) from **Resources** folder (LearnOpenGL/Resources) but I see that paths in c++ code are relative to **LearnOpenGL/out/build/x64-Debug/**.

I've already tried :

- setting property VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY like (also without trailing slash):

```
set_property(TARGET LearnOpenGL PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/")
```

- adding "currentDir" or "cwd" to **CMakeSettings.json** like:

```
"currentDir": "${projectDir}"
```

```
"cwd": "${projectDir}"
```

but there is no effect of any of those changes. Does anyone have some ideas what else can I do? Or maybe I'm doing here something wrong?

Comment: How do you run your executable? The property `VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY` affects only on running the executable inside Visual Studio by hitting "debug" or "run".

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've selected the CMakeLists.txt as a startup item, a then pressed the button (with green arrow) to run the project, is that what you're referring to? I also run once or twice by pressing F10 to immediately start debugging.

Comment: Hm, in that case setting the property `VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY` should work. Not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Have you selected your executable as startup project via the solution explorer? How exactly does the program fail? Does it run, but just cannot open some files or is there some different error, like e.g. dlls not being found?

Comment: @fabian I've selected CMakeLists.txt in solution explorer as startup item. The only problem I encounter is that it can't open some files (e.g. 3D object models - .obj), the program works - it runs, it creates window, it prints messages in console etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add *currentDir* property to your *launch.vs.json* which will typically be in *${workspaceRoot}/.vs* directory.

To access it from Visual Studio 2022 CMake project you can follow these steps:

In the solution explorer click on *Switch between solutions and available views* button:

[image]

Then click on *CMake Targets View*
[image]

Now right click on your project and press *Add Debug Configuration* in context menu

[image]

This will open *launch.vs.json* file where you can edit *currentDir* property, for example - my project *02_texture.exe* should start in root directory so my launch config looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "",
      "name": "CMakeLists.txt"
    },
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "02_texture.exe (02_texture\\02_texture.exe)",
      "name": "02_texture.exe (02_texture\\02_texture.exe)",
      "currentDir": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I need to mention one more thing - after those steps I had to also change the project in the "start" button (the one with green arrow) so it could work.

Comment: Note: the context option seems to now be under "[Right Click] -> Debug and Launch Settings -> [Target Name]" instead of "[Right Click] -> Add Debug Configuration".

Answer (score 0):

As an additional tip related to the answer from stjepano, it is also possible to save that `launch.vs.json` file next to you `CMakeLists.txt`. This is convenient as it allows to save the `launch.vs.json` file in your source code repository and, consequently, share that configuration with your co-workers (its default location, in the `.vs` folder doesn't make it possible as that folder should not be commited).

I could not find documentation on Microsoft's website explaining this was possible and had to rely on blind experiments to find this "hidden" feature, so I though it was interesting to note.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also currently working myself through the examples of https://www.learnopengl.com and I also use CMake to generate Visual Studio solutions / projects.
I ran into the same issue with loading shaders and textures. They were not found when running the sample apps from Visual Studio Debugger. My solution was:

1. copy shaders and textures via a short npm script to both the build/Debug and build/Release subdirectories. You could also use a batch file.
2. In CMakeLists.txt, add the following code so that visual studio debugger runs in build/Debug or build/Release respectively and not in build/ which is default:

```
#set visual studio's working directory for debugging to 'build/debug' respectively 'build/release' instead of 'build'
set_property(TARGET triangle-sample  PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR})
```

Comment: When running from command-line in case you don't need to debug just change current working directory to build/Debug or build/Release and start the app.